What is ではつまらない here? Why does it mean?
日向から与えられるものであるが故に、生ぬるい刺激ではつまらないのだ...
The character is receiving a gift from her lover and thinks this... Why is ではつまらない used? "It's something I received from Hinata, but consequently  the lukewarm stimulus/thrill is dull?

Yes, it's saying half-baked stimulation won't satisfy the speaker. You may be asking this because 生ぬるい already carries a negative connotation, but the sentence makes sense because つまらない is more direct.

生ぬるい刺激ではつまらない: OK
そんな刺激では生ぬるい: OK
つまらない刺激では生ぬるい: Weird

